# Find $\int_{|z|=r}\frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2}$ where $|a| \neq r$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Trying to find

$$\int_{|z|=r}\frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2}$$

where $|a| \neq r$. Was trying to use the maximum length estimate. For both case $|a|>r$ and $|a|<r$, I got the same answer zero.

Comment: It obviously can't be zero, since you're integrating something positive with respect to a positive measure.....

Comment: Then what will be the approach?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* You can use the relation $|\mathrm{d}z| = \frac{r}{iz} \, \mathrm{d}z$ to write

$$ \int_{|z|=r}\frac{|\mathrm{d}z|}{|z-a|^2} = \frac{r}{i} \int_{|z|=r}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(z-a)(r^2-\bar{a}z)}. $$

The denominator has simple poles at $z = a$ and at $z = r^2/\bar{a}$. Notice that if $|a| \neq r$, then exactly one of them lies in the circle $|z| = r$. Thus applying the residue theorem, you can conclude that

$$ \int_{|z|=r}\frac{|\mathrm{d}z|}{|z-a|^2} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2\pi r}{r^2-|a|^2}, & |a| < r \\
\dfrac{2\pi r}{|a|^2-r^2}, & |a| > r
\end{cases}. $$

Comment: How can I get |dz|=$\frac{r}{iz}$dz?

Comment: Let $z=re^{it}$. Then $dz=i\cdot re^{it}dt=izdt$. It follows that $dt=\frac{1}{iz}dz$ and $|dz|=|z|dt=\frac{r}{iz}dz$. Notice that in the last equality we used that the integral is over the circle $|z|=r$.